# Changing SQL string query to parametized query; syntax for calling database class file using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I need to convert a bunch of string query insert statements  into parameterized queries.

Some of the fields have conditionals, ie

```
 string     ActualNumStudents;
            if (txtActualNumStudents.Text == "")
                ActualNumStudents = "0";
            else
                ActualNumStudents = txtActualNumStudents.Text;
```

Can I use the string  ActualNumStudents  instead of txtActualNumStudents.Text ?   I have found similar questions, but not exactly this situation.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActualNumStudents", txtActualNumStudents.Text);
```

Comment: What is the type in Database ? is it `int` ?

Comment: @Habib that's the real question.....

Comment: Total apologies - I should have been clearer. ActualNumStudents is numeric (18,0).  There are some other conditionals where the values are nvarchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an [in-line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) if statement :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActualNumStudents", txtActualNumStudents.Text == "" ? "0" : txtActualNumStudents.Text);
```

Comment: Thank you.  Some of the conditional statements are for varchar fields like this:
`string isCurrent = "";
if (rbtYes.Checked)
isCurrent = "Yes";
else
isCurrent = "No";`


And some are DateTime: 
`string Time;
   if (txtTime.Text == "")
    Time = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
else
Time = txtTime.Text;`


Do you know what syntax is needed for inline if statements in those cases?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use like

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActualNumStudents", txtActualNumStudents.Text == "" ? "0" : txtActualNumStudents.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can as long as it's the correct type it doesn't matter if it's in a variable / control or direct via "somedata"

Answer (score 0):

Before a precise answer, you need to tell what is the type of ActualNumStudents in your sp?
In case it is a number, then you can do the inline version suggested by many people here, in case that is any type of string (char, varchar,nchar, nvarchar ,...), then you also need to know what to pass in case on empty entry (most probably, it is numeric...)

Comment: Thank you. My apologies - I should have noted the type  ActualNumStudents is numeric. There are some other conditionals where the fields are a string type of nvarchar

Comment: Sorry - I should have been more clear.   ActualNumStudents is numeric. There are some fields that are nvarchar.   
There a couple of Yes or no  char fields where the values come from radio buttons.   (I know that is not the ideal method for radio button data, but I am having to work with what I was given).  what would the syntax be in those cases?  Thank you so much.